# How to preserve dgn cad file attributes when exporting from microstation and importing into Arcmap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert, cad, microstation

I'm trying to import water utility lines from Microstation into ArcMap. The water utility lines are symbolized by size in Microstation, but when I try to view the attribute table in ArcMap the attributes seem to have not transfered over, the pipe size attribute is blank. Any advice or a direction to turn? I'm poor with microstation/CAD but have a solid background in ArcGIS. Thanks!

Comment: How are you exporting the information?  Using a file reading a DB?

Comment: From Arc Catalog, Im finding the water utility CAD dataset I have. I've converted that Polyline CAD file to a shapefile, but the pipe size attribute I want is absent from the attribute table. In Microstation, the pipes are colored differently by size (each unique pipe size is on its own "level" in microstation) I want to symbolize by pipe size in ArcMap but cannot seem to transfer those attributes from Microstation.

Comment: Have you tried CADtoGeodatabase, located in the Conversion Toolset? This will import all the DGN data into a File Geodatabase.

Answer (score 1):

Now i have no idea how it's done with ArcMap/Catalog , but with when using FME to do file type conversion dgn has level, color, etc values which you need to decode to Arc* system. Note that in dgn you have allways level number but no name.

In your case , you might have to do it level by level.

Comment: i do shp->dgn->shp conversion by level name with FME. works great (but cad file to geo file conversion are still annoying baucause cad people think diffrently than gis people ) I recommend getting FME for this kind of work